# How to add pictures in slideshow in django

Tags: jquery, python, html, django

I have this html code for a slide show:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
                <img class="slide-image" src="http://placehold.it/800x300" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img class="slide-image" src="http://placehold.it/800x300" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img class="slide-image" src="http://placehold.it/800x300" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want the slide show to display the pictures that the user uploads. I keep the pictures in a list and send the list when rendering the html, and I want to iterate throw that list to display the pictures. How cant I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first:

```
pip install Pillow
```

then you can use the ImageField in models like this:

```
class Blog(models.Model):

    avator = models.ImageField(upload_to='avator')
    ....
```

then the file with be upload to:

> MEDIA_ROOT/upload_to/filename

then if your

> MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

and

> urlpatterns + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

you can get the file with:

> http[s]://host:port/media/upload_to/filename

in template it will be:

```
{% for i in Blog_querysets %}
    <a href="/media/{{ i.avator }}">
{% end for %}
```

you can try something out

Answer (score 1):

create model with ImageField for pictures (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/),
create form for upload image (https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/forms/), create view for user, witch show and processing uploading form and save uploaded images in you model(https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/views/),
create another view, witch get all images from model and render you gallery template, iterate images over django teplate tag {% for %} (https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/templates/).
for easy understanding, see galery example(upload over admin): https://github.com/samuelmh/django-smh_gallery